# writing a single servlet to add/edit/delete an Item and also to list items

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to create a single Servlet to handle listing of some `Item`s, adding new items, editing existing items and also deletion of items.

I wrote JSP pages for edit an item and showing a list of items. In `itemslisting.jsp`, I have put delete and edit links for each item but I am not very sure about how to construct the methods in Servlet.

`itemslisting.jsp`

```xml
...
<table>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${items}" varStatus="listCount">

<tr><td>${listCount.count} </td>
<c:url value="edititem" var="edititemurl">

    <c:param name="itemId" value="${item.item_id}" />

</c:url>
<td><a href="${edititemurl }" >${item.name}</a></td>
<c:url value="deleteitem" var="deleteitemurl">

    <c:param name="itemId" value="${item.item_id}" />

</c:url>

<td><a href="${deleteitemurl}" >DELETE</a></td>

</tr>

</c:forEach>

</table>
...
<a href="<c:url value="addItem"/>">add new item </a>
...
```

In our training we were asked to create separate servlets to add, edit, list and delete Items. In those cases mapping can be done for each of these urls to the appropriate servlet but it feels silly to create that many servlets. How do I configure the different urls in the above jsp to a single *ItemServlet*? Do I have to pass some extra parameter to indicate the operation, say like `edititem` along with the edititemurl?

I tried to create a skeleton of the `doGet()` method:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws ServletException, IOException {
    String additemop = req.getParameter("additemoperation");
    String edititem = req.getParameter("additemoperation");
    String itemId =  req.getParameter("itemId");
    ...
    if(additemop!=null){
      showAddItemPage(req,resp);
    }
    else if((edititemop!=null) && (itemId != null)){
      showEditItemPage(req,resp);
    }
    else{
      showListItemsPage(req,resp);
    }

}
```

I don't know if this is the way to do this, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but nobody does it this way anymore. Typical is to use a framework such as springframework. Then there is very nice built in support for MVC mapping controllers to views.

Comment: I've fixed it but FYI: no spaces before commas, one space after them. If there are only two items in a list, just use *and* instead of a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a parameter with your url, like:

```
myapp/item?action=get
```

Using separate urls for these is easier and less error-prone, though. That is likely why you were taught that way in the first place.

You need to be careful what you do with HTTP GET and what you do with POST. Using GET like you do in your example (to add an item) is bad, you don't want to do anything that modifies data with GET. Especially don't make deletion a GET, or the first webcrawler that comes along can wipe out your database. :-O  Also check out something called [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), it is a common pattern for avoiding duplicate form submissions and making your pages bookmarkable.

I recommend checking out a rapid-development framework, like [Play](http://www.playframework.org/). The raw jsp/servlet stuff here is just too tedious to grind out. You have already been through the hard way once, so you won't be missing out on anything.